# Unhandled Exception when initializing firebase on windows

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Hi guys first time here on stack overflow.

I am currently building an app using flutter with firebase as the backend.

My target platforms are Windows and android

The android app builds fine

The windows app throws :

> ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception:
> PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on
> channel., null, null)

this only happens when I use :

```
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

I have also tried :

```
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: "myapi",
    appId: "appid",
    messagingSenderId: "senderid",
    projectId: "projectid",
    storageBucket: "buckedid",
    databaseURL: 'databaseurl',
  ));
```

As stated this works fine on android but not windows

I have the latest dependencies for Firebase

I have tried flutter pub outdated and it returns no Firebase dependencies

I have tried flutter pub upgrade

I have tried flutter clear

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you are using the the latest versions of firebase you'd want to follow through the newest way of initializing firebase with firebase CLI. See this https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli starting off by activating firebase cli

```
have something like this
// Import the generated file
import 'firebase_options.dart'; //this provides the current platform options via the currentPlatform getter from the DefaultFirebaseOptions class
...

await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: const FirebaseOptions(
  apiKey: "API KEY",//<<==
  appId: "ID",//<<==
  messagingSenderId: "IF ANY",//<<==
  projectId: "Project ID",//<<==
),
...
```

Comment: Hi I have activated firebase cli and have linked my project.

Comment: From your code it shows you haven't added yet. check updated answer

Comment: Package flutterfire_cli is currently active at version 0.2.7.

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes follow through the link please.

Comment: Now I am greeted with : [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for windows - you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.   But when running flutterfire configure I see there is no windows option, could you advise?

Comment: Do it manually then. Check updated code

Comment: I did it manually and back to the original exception error

Comment: make sure you have both GoogleService-Info.plist added correctly in android and ios

Comment: Ok done but unfortunately still  ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null) when trying to build windows